# Set parentheses in Querydsl

Tags: java, sql, querydsl, parentheses

How is it possible to set parentheses in Querydsl? If I have a complex boolean expression, for example

```
b1 and b2 and ((b3 or b4) and b5) and ((b6 and b7) or b8)
```

it would be nice to get a select statement nesting the boolean expression like in this example. The best result with Querydsl I got was

```
b1 and b2 and (b3 or b4 and b5) and (b5 and b6 or b7)
```

My code looked like this:

```
BooleanExpression be = obj.v1.eq(key)
    .and(obj.v2.eq(..))
    .and(obj.v3.goe(..).or(obj.v3.loe(..)).and(obj.v4.eq(..))
    .and(obj.v5.goe(..).and(obj.v5.loe(..)).or(obj.v5.goe(..))
```

Answer (score 2):

The result that QueryDSL generates is logically equivalent.

However, if you really want the parentheses there, QueryDSL has the `WRAPPED` operator that wraps an expression within parentheses.

Use:

```java
Expressions.predicate(Ops.WRAPPED, firstExpression.and(secondExpression))
```

Comment: While we add this at runtime, it's added parentheses but while its generate SQL statement, its remove parentheses and execute as per precedence

Comment: The parentheses only remain if its Querydsl that generates the SQL. In your case it is likely your ORM, probably Hibernate, that generates the SQL and removes the unneeded parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I tried and understand that ORM remove unneeded parentheses are removed and its executed on this precedence: parentheses -> AND -> OR. 
tried on (Spring boot + hibernate + Querydsl + postgres)